# eslint+ flow : 'attribute' is missing in props validation (Object with identifier)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, flowtype

I'm facing a weird issue today,

I have a React component which is typed with flow (a.k.a flowtype for SEO), and for some reason it shows a typing error here, here's the simplified code.

```
type Props = {
  someObject: { [string]: string },
};

class ComponentOne extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      // No idea why there's a linting error, seems like a bug

      <div className={this.props.someObject.someKey} />
    );
  }
}

const WithEnhancements = enhance(magic)(ComponentOne);

export default () => (
  <RenderPropComponent>
    {({ someProp }) => {
      return <WithEnhancements someProp={someProp} />;
    }}
  </RenderPropComponent>
);
```

The error is `'someObject.someKey' is missing in props validation`. 
I'm hitting a wall and have no idea what might be causing it, the same typing for the same data structure used in other components works absolutely fine, could it be a bug with `eslint` not being happy with multi-components files  ?

**Update: Seems like an eslint bug, for some reason it works when the prop is destructured like this and then using `someObject.someKey`:**

```
const { someObject } = this.props;
```

Comment: > // No idea why there's a linting error, seems like a bug

Looks like this one line is missing before return in `render`:
```javascript 
const {someObject} = this.props;
```

Comment: @frontendgirl The code I posted and which I anon'd the vars was missing something, of course I've used  `{this.props.someObject.someKey}`. Well as I mentioned, destructuring works but I do NOT want to destructure just for one prop, this is not clean code IMO and wouldn't be consistent with our codebase, so this is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently an eslint bug, reported [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1280). It can be remedied by destructuring the props as mentioned by frontendgirl, and while that may not seem like clean code you'd only need to do it for components where you have a map object (one with an indexer property, the `{ [string]: string }`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @andrewsouthpaw. Searched for the issue but couldn't find one, I've raised a new one but this seems to be it !